# Apache Tomcat doesn't update my webapp

Tags: tomcat, war

I'm developing a webapp using Apache Tomcat. When I make a change to the HTML/CSS/JS or JAVA code, I create a new .war file, I undeploy the previous one through Tomcat manager App and I deploy the new .war file. The problem is that Tomcat keeps the old file. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delete the folder "tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/YourWebApplication" and empty your browser cache.